# Render a PDF document inside Visualforce page which renderAs PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I've a requirement to create a Visualforce page renderAs PDF.
This page has one section in which I want to render information which is stored in the another document, this document could be Attachment or Document record.

Is there any way to render a complete document inside a Visualforce page which is already a PDF?

Comment: It's definitely possible to display PDF files in a VisualForce page, though your question is unclear so not sure if that is helpful or not. If you already have a PDF, why is "renderAs=PDF" important? Is the page a mix of PDF and non-PDF content? Screenshots might help clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. You can only render HTML and images. You would need to store your other document as HTML if you want to render it in the PDF.